# Using the definition of a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose I want to calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} x^2$ using the definition of the limit. i.e

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. when $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon, |x - a| < \delta$.

So, here we would have $|x^2 - 9| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |x+3||x-3| < \epsilon$. What do I do with $|x+3|$ in this case?

Comment: Without loss of generality, one can take $\epsilon < 1$, implying that $|x + 3| < 4$.

Comment: I think you switched order in the definition of your limit.. Also the limit here expresses continuity of the function $f$ at the point $a$, is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

$$|x^2-9|=|x+3||x-3| \le (|x|+3)|x-3| \tag{1}$$

If $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon/7)$, then we have $|x-3|< \varepsilon/7$ and $|x-3|<1$, in particular the last inequality give us $|x|<4$. Using all of  these in (1) we have:

$$(|x|+3)|x-3|<7|x-3|< \varepsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\delta$ works for the value $\epsilon = 1$, it works for all values of $\epsilon$ that are at *least* $1$ (do you see why? If our $\delta$ is good enough to ensure our error is at most $1$, it works for less stringent errors). Thus, we can assume without loss of generality that $\epsilon \le 1$, in which case

$$|x + 3| \le 3 + 1 = 4$$

can be bounded above.

Comment: Okay so what your saying is that $|x+3|$ will always have a value that is higher then $|x-3|$ unless you choose $0$ for $x$. I guess that makes sense. How would one finish writing the definition of the limit with the random example I made up then?